# Adding ASCII art into a Java String

Tags: java, string, ascii

I just finished a flight manager program and was wanting to put some ASCII art in it just to make it look better. However, since there are "escape characters" I can not do so. Is there anyway to bypass this? Or am I just stuck with a bland looking menu?

Comment: It's software, you can do pretty much anything.  Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do and what's not working?

Comment: The program is run from terminal. I was trying to put in an air plane art as well as a menu name in ASCII art. Gives me errors saying there are "escape characters"

Comment: Oh I get it, the terminal often being called command line, or in Windows it would be DOS, right?  I get it now.  :)

Comment: Backslashes need to be doubled.

Comment: ASCII art is so ... 1970's :-)

Comment: @MeenaO - Checkout this Q&A.

Comment: You need to write the string in a way that have \\ instead of \ and if you use ' as string separator you need to write \' instead of '. The other solution is to put ASCII art in `<script type="ascii" id="ascii">` and use `document.getElementById('ascii');`. Also if ASCII art have newlines you need to put `\n\` at the end of each line or use backtics (ES6 template literals) as string separator if you do that you need to escape backtics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this to escape your string and then embed the result in code.
http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for! Thanks very much!